# How to get the CSS value of an Image say a Green check mark or a red exclamation mark

Tags: java, selenium

I'm trying to get the css value of an image,having green check mark when a device is active and a red exclamation mark if inactive, and following is the xpath of that image - //*[@class='tickImg pull-right'], using the method getCSSValue is not fetching the result. could anyone please let me know the mistake that i'm doing here.
My actual testing involves me asserting if the devices show a green check mark if they are connected and red exclamation if not.

Answer (score 1):

String ImgColor = driver.findElement(By.name("Img")).getCssValue("background-color");
or
String ImageColor = driver.findElement(By.name("Img")).getCssValue("color");

Hope this will help.